# Idea of how to approach Exponential Functions Questions Please

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, exponential-function, absolute-value

Can someone help me on how to approach this question?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is, to put it nicely, implausible.  It assumes that the seeds have been hidden in sets of $100$, perhaps by a mathematically minded squirrel. It also assumes that searching for Type 1 and for Type 2 cannot be done simultaneously. And the answer is obvious, since the good stuff is easiest to find. But let us continue, but not without lodging a complaint at this parody of applied mathematics.

The expected caloric find if we spend the proportion $x_1$ searching for Type 1, and $x_2$ for Type 2, is
$$500x_1^3+300x_2^5.$$
Substituting $1-x_1$ for $x_2$, we arrive at the function
$$V(x_1)=500x_1^3+300(1-x_1)^5.$$
Differentiation yields
$$1500(x_1^2-(1-x_1)^4)=0.$$
So we want to solve $x_1^2=(1-x_1)^4$. Since everything is non-negative, we get equivalently $x_1=(1-x_1)^2$, or equivalently $x_1^2-3x_1+1=0$. This has the solution $x_1=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, and therefore $x_2=\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Calculation shows that this is a horrible strategy. By using the second derivative, or by examining the first derivative, we see that in fact this gives an absolute minimum caloric intake.

So we need to look at the endpoints. It is clear that best strategy is to look for Type 1 only.

Comment: How did you derive at the constants of 500 and 300 ?!

Comment: Never mind, so you are considering the caloric value of each seed

Comment: How did you do part b to find the critical points? You set the equation to 0 then used the quadratic equation to find both x's? But where did the 1500(x1^2−(1−x1)4)=0 come from? and the x1=(1−x1)^4 and for the x2

Comment: I differentiated $500x_1^3 +300(1-x_1)^5$. The derivative of the first term is $(500)(3)x_1^2$. The derivative of the second term is $(300)(-1)(5)(1-x_1)^4$ (Chain Rule). Then things simplify. There is a common factor of $1500$. So we want $x_1^2=(1-x_1)^4$. Take the square root of both sides. We end up with $x_1=(1-x_1)^2$. Expand. We have a quadratic equation and use the Quadratic Formula.

Comment: If you expand (1-x1) you do not get x1^2−3x1+1=0.

Comment: Wouldnt it be x1^2−2x1+1=0. Isn't it -2x1 instead of -3x1?

Comment: When we took the square root we got $x_1=(1-x_1)^2$. Expand the right side. We get $x_1=x_1^2-2x_1+1$, which simplifies to $x_1^2-3x_1+1=0$.

Comment: That is the answer the part c? isnt it? For part b to find the critical points to know it if it is maximum or a minimum shouldn't I differentiate it and equal it to 0 and if it is a positive then it is a minimum and if it is a max then it is a negative..?!

Comment: It is most of the answer to part (b). The critical point occurs at $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. By comparing the value of the original function at this point with the endpoint values, or by the second derivative test (second derivative is $\gt 0$), or by examining the behaviour of the first derivative, we find that our function attains a local min at $\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  For part (c), we evaluate the original function at the endpoints $x_1=1$ and $x_1=0$, find where max occurs.